# enabling multi factor authentication on openssh (publickey + password)

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'd like to make it so that you need to provide the SSH server with a password and an RSA key to login.

I can make password protected RSA keys but in that case the password for the RSA key isn't being sent to the server and I want the server to be evaluating the password (in addition to the publickey).

How might I do this? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up `AuthenticationMethods` in `sshd_config`, for example:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

as in the manual pages for [`sshd_config(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).